# legend in dhtmlx vertical barchart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlx vartical barchart.
I have loaded the barchart dynamically using json object.
now,I want to know what is legend?and how to display legend in dhtmlx chart

Answer (score 0):

You can set legend in chart config. Here is the link to similar sample:

http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxChart/samples/06_bar_chart/06_series.html